# How to prove that $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$

In my exercise book I have that proof:

> Let $B=2\mathbb{N}+1$ and $A=2\mathbb{N}$
>
> $A,B $ disjoint and $A+B=\aleph_0$

But to me it looks like example and not a proof.

Comment: What does "foreigenes" mean?

Comment: @CameronBuie non-priest , English is'nt my first language

Comment: For any set $X$ of cardinality $\aleph_0,$ there is a bijection $\phi:X\to\mathbb N.$ The proof you gave uses that implicitly. I'm sure you can work out the rest of the details in the proof.

Comment: @CameronBuie $A\cap B=\emptyset$

Comment: In cardinal arithmetic, if you can set up bijections then that will give cardinalities.  So any proven example that $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ amounts to a general proof.

Comment: What definition of cardinal addition do you have? With the one I can think of right away, the proof you're quoting is indeed a proof.

Comment: @Henry I think I will take your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set $A$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$, then there is a bijection $A \to \mathbb{N}$. 
Now, since $\mathbb{N} \to 2\mathbb{N}+1$ and $\mathbb{N} \to 2\mathbb{N}$ are bijections, then given two sets $X$ and $Y$ with cardinality $\aleph_0$, there are two bijections
$$ \phi: X \to \mathbb{N} \to 2\mathbb{N} +1 $$
and
$$ \psi: Y \to \mathbb{N} \to 2\mathbb{N} $$
Therefore there is a bijection from the disjoint union $X \cup Y \to \mathbb{N}$ , that is "$\phi \cup \psi$" (it is $\phi$ on the $X$ part and $\psi$ on the $Y$ part of the set).

Recall that $\mathbb{N} = 2\mathbb{N} \cup 2\mathbb{N}+1$ and you're done:
$$\aleph_0 + \aleph_0 = |X| + |Y| = |X \cup Y| = \aleph_0$$